# System.Web.WebPages.Razor deploy issue

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I used all methods I could find to deploy MVC3 project into IIS 7 but still have this error when I open website.

Any clue?

> No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' ni
>   una de sus dependencias. La definición del manifiesto del ensamblado
>   no coincide con la referencia al ensamblado. (Excepción de HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: No se puede cargar el
>   archivo o ensamblado 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' ni una de sus
>   dependencias. La definición del manifiesto del ensamblado no coincide
>   con la referencia al ensamblado. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to
>   determine why the assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
>   could not be loaded.
>
> AVS: El registro del enlace de ensamblado está desactivado. Para
>   habilitar el registro de errores del enlace de ensamblado, establezca
>   el valor de Registro [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog]
>   (DWORD) como 1. Nota: existe una disminución del rendimiento asociada
>   registro de errores del enlace de ensamblado. Para desactivar esta
>   característica, elimine el valor de Registro
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [FileLoadException: No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado
>   'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' ni una de sus dependencias. La
>   definición del manifiesto del ensamblado no coincide con la referencia
>   al ensamblado. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
>   WebMatrix.Security.PreApplicationStartCode.Start() +0
>
> [InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization
>   method Start on type WebMatrix.Security.PreApplicationStartCode threw
>   an exception with the following error message: No se puede cargar el
>   archivo o ensamblado 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' ni una de sus
>   dependencias. La definición del manifiesto del ensamblado no coincide
>   con la referencia al ensamblado. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80131040).] 
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1
>   methods) +423
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods() +306
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +677
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization
>   method Start on type WebMatrix.Security.PreApplicationStartCode threw
>   an exception with the following error message: No se puede cargar el
>   archivo o ensamblado 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' ni una de sus
>   dependencias. La definición del manifiesto del ensamblado no coincide
>   con la referencia al ensamblado. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80131040).] 
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9090876 
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +97
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +256

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crazy day!

I just install [WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=WebMatrix) to Server and it works!!! Pfffff :)

Answer (score 1):

Mr. Haack provided the [answer you are looking for](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/25/bin-deploying-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx) (other than installing the required stuff on every web server).  It works well, especially in a web-farm environment.